# ColdFusion if statement value not returning true instead returns false

Tags: coldfusion

In my code, I'm querying my database to get the city.

I wrote an if statement that says if this city is equal to that value in the db. return this image of that city. However, it's returning a different image which is going to the false block of my if statement.

I did a `cfdump` of the city variable and it returns the city I wanted but for some reason it's returning false instead of true. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
 <cfloop query="testData">
    <cfif #city# EQ 'Portland'>
       <!--- I want it to go to this block --->
       <img src="images/portlandcity.jpg" alt="Portland City">
    <cfelseif #city# EQ 'San Jose'>
       <img src="images/sanjosecity.jpg alt="San Jose City">
    <cfelse>
       <!-- its going to this block instead of going to my Portland city block. --->
       <img src="images/randomcityimage.jpg alt="False block">
    </cfif>

    <!-- Dumped out city variable in the loop and it returns 'Portland'.
         However, it's going to the false block for some reason and I am not sure why --->
    <cfdump var="#city#"> 
 </cfloop>
```

Comment: It's value probably isn't exactly equal to 'Portland'.

Comment: It is though. I did a cfdump of the city variable and it returns exactly 'Portland'

Comment: no extra spaces? tabs? returns? invisible characters you wouldn't see in the dump?

Comment: Do a ltrim(rtrim(city)) in your query. Or check the length of it in ColdFusion. There's whitespace or an invalid character in the field.

Comment: It was whitespace thank you so much I dumped the variable and copy and pasted it onto notepad and it returned 'Portland ' but in the cfdump it showed on the page as 'Portland'

Comment: Just to clean up code, you don't need the # around city in the if statements. You'd only need it if it was in quotes.

Comment: Oh okay thank you I didn't know that I'm still getting used to the language. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following in your code to prevent items with spaces:

Note I took out the # around your variable and added the trim() function.
In a If statement you do not need to use # signs.

```
 <cfif trim(city) EQ 'Portland'>
   <img src="images/portlandcity.jpg" alt="Portland City"> <!--- I want it to go to this block --->
<cfelseif trim(city) EQ 'San Jose'>
   <img src="images/sanjosecity.jpg alt="San Jose City">
<cfelse>
   <img src="images/randomcityimage.jpg alt="False block"> <!-- its going to this block instead of going to my Portland city block. --->
</cfif>
```